# change the sequence of an objects Only which contains duplicate items in an array?

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

1. I don't want to change the original sequence of Objects in an array.
2. But I need to get the items in sequence when the location and place are equal.
3. I tried but I need for an and condition.

```js
        var sim=[{name:"vinod",location:"asia",place:"simha"},{name:"ajay",location:"zyd", place:"aaa"},{name:"ram",location:"raj",place:"zzz"},
{name:"abhirma",location:"zyd",place:"aaa"},
{name:"ram",location:"raj",place:"zzz"}];

    
    sim.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.location.localeCompare(b.location);
    });
    console.log(sim);
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: What do you mean by "get the items in sequence" ?

Comment: Which sequence do you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Muhammad : down one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
const unique = new Set(sim.map(a=> JSON.stringify(a)));
console.log(unique);  
const newarr= Array.from(unique).map(b=>JSON.parse(b));
console.log(newarr)
```

variable  "unique " will be return the unique value and removed the duplicated value  and variable  "newarr"  will return the array of object

Comment: Code only answers usually aren't useful. Please add some context.